# How to use a DbSet<> property present in DbContext class as a parameter for Action-method present in Controller class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a login and registration web application.In the [HttpPost] login method (present in UserController class) i want to pass the " DbSet Users" property as a parameter , but i am getting an error.[This is the screenshot of the DbContext class which contains the DbSet property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIHcV.png)[This is the screenshot of the action method present in the Controller class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPjOu.png)

```
         public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private  readonly DataContext db;
        public UsersController(DataContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Register(User usr)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(usr);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Some Error Occured!");
            }
            return View(usr);
        }
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(Users users )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                    var obj = db.users.Where(u => u.Username == (users.Username) && u.Password == (users.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        TempData["UserId"] = obj.UserId.ToString();
                        TempData["Username"] = obj.Username.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
                    }
            }
            return View(users);
        }
        public IActionResult LoggedIn()
        {
            if (TempData["UserId"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found its solution. We can simply Create a ViewModel class which will contain username and Password properties (which is required at the login time) and simply we can use this ViewModel class as the parameter in Login Action method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Code tags (printscreens are super-annoying), because they are much easier to read and you can for example copy-paste from them.
You must get an DataContext instance into your controller. Isn't there a dependency-injection in ASP.NET? If so, just inject your DataContext as a service.
Your code, as you pasted it, cannot work - class Users (you use Users as a class name) doesn't exist in your scope.

Comment: How can i create an instance for AppDbContext in my controller as the AppDbContext class contains a constructor.

Comment: Oh sorry you named it as DataContext, sorry.

Comment: Also, if you want to have this database set as a parameter of Login method, are you sure that the parameter is inserted when this method is called?

Comment: i have already done dependency injection here in my controller class , still i am unable to get the  DbSet<>Users  property as the parameter for my action method.

Comment: It is some time since I last worked with ASP. NET but I think that dependency injections injects into constructors (so you need to save your DataContext into some property, which you will access from Login method.

Comment: i have attached the whole controller class code, now can u see and  tell where am i making mistake?

Comment: The Login method with Users input parameter is never called IMO. Try to remove the Users parameter and comment out the previous method (the Login with return view). If it does not work, place a breakpoint in the constructor and check if db gets correctly initialised by DataContext

Comment: i am unable to get rid out of this problem.